# How to implement the selenium on public browser

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation

WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();

It automatically open the Private firefox browser. Is there any option to open normal browser instead of Private browser.

Comment: I don't get why some people come to Stackoverflow as their first source to solve questions concerning third party applications. Why not try the official selenium documentation where you would find the answer quite quick: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver

Answer (score 0):

Not without some serious work on your end.  When you create a new WebDriver instance, a firefox instance is started that uses no user profiles.  It's like a fresh installation.  WebDriver installs a profile on this clean browser instance and installs an extension that runs a little micro web server that listens for instructions from your java program.  This little server is what enables two way communication between the browser's javascript environment and your remote java program.

The relationship between the running instance of this firefox web server extension and the WebDriver instance running in your java program is a tightly controlled partnership.  It's not part of their criteria to allow you to do what you're asking, so you would have to venture far outside the boundaries of what they support.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly invoke the browser without giving setProperty in firefox for selenium versions <3.0

#### Firefox in Selenium 3

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","path of the driver");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Replace **webdriver.gecko.driver** with **webdriver.firefox.marionette** if above doesn't work.

#### Chrome browser

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path of the driver");
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
```

#### IE browser

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","path of the driver");
    WebDriver driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

#### Headless Browser

```
    WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
```